# Can't make WhatsApp calls over Wi-fi on iOS14

Tags: iphone, ios, network, wifi

I have an iPhone 11. Yesterday while it was running iOS 13, all was fine, I could make WhatsApp calls over my Wi-Fi. I updated to iOS 14 in the morning. And now when I'm trying to make a call on WhatsApp, I get this message.

[image]

I can still call normally over cellular data, but not over my home Wi-Fi.
The receiving end clicks on "accept call", but nothing happens.

Internet suggests me to use VPN, since my country is blocking WhatsApp. I highly doubt it, since my country is Germany. I have deleted and installed WhatsApp again - but it didn't help. It's a corporate phone, but before today everything was working fine, so I doubt it's them.

Anybody has ever had this kind of problems?

Comment: Yes absolutely. I am facing similar issue with IPhone 11 ans IOS 14. Unable to make Watsapp call over WiFi. Intact exact similar concern. I am based in India.

Comment: I am also facing the same problem. Please call apple support and report the same. When I called them, they mentioned that no other user had raised this issue and thought it was just my whatsapp. I had deleted and re-installed whatsapp, and I still have the same problem. Mine is also corporate phone. I tried the VPN (New York & Germany) and still it didn;t work. The more people need to make an call support on this issue if it had to be fixed at software level.

Comment: You are not the only ones. I also have the same issue.
I have reinstalled WhatsApp, reset iPhone, but nothing helped

Comment: With the new update (14.0.1) occasionally WhatsApp calls don't work over mobile network either.

Answer (score 2):

While not the same error message, a family member was having trouble with WhatsApp and it looks like a new feature of iOS14 is the culprit.

If you open up the Settings for WhatsApp and make sure that it has `Local Network` access that might solve your issue

[image: WhatsApp Settings Screen with Local Network highlighted]